# Building async web apps with playframework

Tags: asynchronous, playframework, reactive-programming

Actually my question is not only targeting for play framework, but a general question for async programming.

I know that in play, we can use:

```
WS.url(url).get()
```

to make a rest call async by return something like promise/future. (I guess it might be supported by underlying NIO library like netty or spray.io)

So, my question is: to build a fully async web application, every I/O bound operation has better to be async, right? Otherwise, it will be a bottle neck?

Let's say I have a very simple web application which only calls a JDBC and return query value to browser.

In this case, suppose I don't have an async/reactive JDBC driver, will play2 performs better than a servlet solution?

Comment: Wrapping both connection resolution and statement against it in the same async context (Future) is sufficient.

Comment: @applicius That's really *not* sufficient.  You're still tying up a thread with your JDBC connection, it's just a different thread than the one handling incoming connections.  That's an improvement—sure—but you're still blocking on whatever dispatcher the future runs on.

Comment: When you run other async task, you don't know how the execution context will run it, using thread or not. There that's the same, either you're confident in the execution you choose (the Scala standard one, Play one, or another) to run your `Future` in a proper way, or not. If not that's the real question.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's any existing popular async JDBC driver ( or equivalent data persistent solution), I know there's a reactive driver for mongodb, just like to know how people handle mysql/oracle asynchronously.